# Dimension in cm and format

Tags: pixel, microsoft-powerpoint, paper-size

I have to create a powerpoint poster. The following guidelines are given:

[image]

Now I am very confused. In powerpoint I see the options to set the size of the slide:

[image]

But what about format and pixels? After some googling I realized that one can convert pixels to cm. I tried using this converter: http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-centimeters-conversion.html

But the dimensions in pixels seem not to be consistent with the dimensions in size. What am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Pixels do not have a size. So there is no pixel to cm conversion.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I am very newbie in this. Find it very weird that there are so many websites converting from pixels to cm then. 
So is there anyway I can ensure in powerpoint that I meet the pixel requirement?\

Comment: Well i am not. See most people failed to understand units in school. All they understood is: This is super important, but nothing furter. I have to deal with this semi daily. A pixel is a sample, so ask yourself does the question "How many samples are there in a cm?" make sense? Anyway,  They are not asking you to make the document 1080x1920 they are asking you to make it tge same shape so that they can put it on a tv screen.

Comment: Okay got what a pixel is :) 
Just not sure what you mean by "making it tge" . They are indeed going to put it on a tv

Comment: In this case, px to cm, the tool you linked it is totally deceiving and misleading. Do not use that. It probably has sense in other conversions. Not in this one

Comment: @phdstudent ever heard if typos? ill give you a hing g is next to h. You try typing on a phone that decided, in its infinite wisdom, to load 4 languages in the predictive typing bar ;)

Comment: Ah. My apologies. I thought "tge" could be some technical term.

Comment: Well yeah its a very convoluted way to say that your document should have an aspect ratio of 9:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly convert Pixels to cm on PowerPoint.

Powerpoint is not a graphic design software. Images that you drop inside are automatically resampled so you have no control over what pixels behave inside it.

**9:16 is only a relationship, it has no direct correlation to Full HD (1920x1080)**

So saying that 9:16 correspond to 1080x1920 is totally inaccurate.

Powerpoint is a mostly a vector based program, so if you are making a poster on it, (which can be done, but is not ideal) simply go for a physical unit in cm.

In my opinion, use the biggest one that you can fit in your final print.